# Select SVG group's elements inside an <object> tag

Tags: jquery, svg, colors

I have a SVG external file which is called in an `<object>` tag.

```
 <object data="Img/PumpStation/Interfata.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="p1"></object>
```

The SVG contains two groups.

```
 <svg>
   <g id="g1">
      <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="93.75" x2="30.2922" y2="93.75" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
      <stop offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#4F4D4D" />
      <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,3.266V37.5h23.423v-0.45V3.266l-1.577-2.703L27.59,0   h-0.676h-1.239H10.248L7.545,1.577L6.982,2.703L6.869,3.266" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="78.1523" x2="30.2922" y2="78.1523" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
      <stop offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
      <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,34.347h23.423" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="105.8555" x2="30.2922" y2="105.8555" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
      <stop offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
      <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,6.645h23.423" />
   </g>
   <g id="g2">
     <linearGradient id="linearColors" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
       <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
       <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
       <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
       <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
       <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
       <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
   <circle r="120" cx="150" cy="150" class="external-circle" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors)"></circle>
   </g>
 </svg>
```

And a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="StartP1" class="startP btn btn-light" runat="server" Text="Start P1" Style="width: 100%" />
```

I know how to replace all `stop-color` from the `stop` tags on click action. I do it by using this jQuery function:

```
    jQuery('.startP').on('click', function () {            
        $("object").contents().find('stop').each(function () {
            var color = jQuery(this).css('stop-color');
            if (color === 'rgb(77, 77, 77)') {
                jQuery(this).css('stop-color', '#00ff00');
            }
        });
    });
```

My question is how could I implement the jQuery function only for the group with the `id="g1"` and not for both groups of my SVG?

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to reference the object you want to transform. You need to remember [how that works](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm) in `Jquery`: `$("object")` selects any `object`, `$(".object")` selects any element with `object` class and `$("#object")` selects any element with `object` id. When you say `$("object").contents().find('stop')`, you select any `stop` element inside an `object` element. If you want to refer only to a `stop` inside the `#g1` element, you can do it in several ways, like:

- `$("object").contents().find('#g1').contents().find('stop')`
- `$("object #g1 stop")`

I have prepared a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/mohingudino/pen/abzJOwz) with your function adapted in several ways. You have four buttons to change the color of both objects (I had to change the end of the gradient of the second object to have one color in common with the first), only the first, only the second or to reset to default.

**EDIT after comment**

Now the question is way more general. The problem is not only how to select one particular object. Issues with that:

- Your svg file needs an `xmlns` link.
- You need to make sure that the `object` content is loaded before setting events (for instance, with `$(window).load()`.
- Jquery not always plays nice with the content of an object ([this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4045), for instance).

So here is a mixed solution (not the only possible one):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>



$(window).load(function(){

var svg = document.getElementById("p1").contentDocument.documentElement;


  $('.startP').on('click', function () {            
        $(svg).contents().find("stop").each(function () {
            var color = jQuery(this).css('stop-color');
            if (color === 'rgb(77, 77, 77)') {
                jQuery(this).css('stop-color', '#00ff00');
            }
        });
    });

  $('.startOne').on('click', function () {            
        $(svg).contents().find("#SVGID_2_ stop,#SVGID_3_ stop,#SVGID_4_ stop").each(function () {
            var color = jQuery(this).css('stop-color');
            if (color === 'rgb(77, 77, 77)') {
                jQuery(this).css('stop-color', '#00ff00');
            }
        });
    });

  $('.startTwo').on('click', function () {   
        $(svg).contents().find("#linearColors stop").each(function () {
            var color = jQuery(this).css('stop-color');
            if (color === 'rgb(77, 77, 77)') {
                jQuery(this).css('stop-color', '#00ff00');
            }
        });
    });

$('.restart').on('click', function () {            
        $(svg).contents().find('stop').each(function () {
            var color = jQuery(this).css('stop-color');

            if (color === 'rgb(0, 255, 0)') {
                jQuery(this).css('stop-color', '#4D4D4D');
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="startP">both</button> 
<button class="startOne">one</button> 
<button class="startTwo">two</button> 
<button class="restart">restart</button> 
<div></div>
<object data="delme.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="p1"><img src="tfs860830.jpg" /></object>



</body>
</html>
```

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="objsvg">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="93.75" x2="30.2922" y2="93.75" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
  <stop offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#4F4D4D" />
  <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
  <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="78.1523" x2="30.2922" y2="78.1523" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
  <stop offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
  <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
  <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="105.8555" x2="30.2922" y2="105.8555" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
  <stop offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
  <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
  <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearColors" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
   <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
   <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
   <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
   <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
   <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#4D4D4D"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
   <g id="g1">
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,3.266V37.5h23.423v-0.45V3.266l-1.577-2.703L27.59,0   h-0.676h-1.239H10.248L7.545,1.577L6.982,2.703L6.869,3.266" />

    <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,34.347h23.423" />
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,6.645h23.423" />
   </g>
   <g id="g2">
   <circle r="120" cx="150" cy="150" class="external-circle" stroke-width="4" fill="none" stroke="url(#linearColors)"></circle>
   </g>
 </svg>
```

I have also moved the `linearGradient` elements to the `defs` section. Now the code refers to them directly, not to `#g1` or `#g2`.

*Edit 2*

I have managed to set up a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dgfuxtWCwciMbXS0mGSt?p=preview) with the example. Please, notice that I called the svg `delme.svg`.

*Edit 3*

If you cannot modify the `svg`, I would use Jquery to get the svg code, then insert it inline into the DOM. This way, you do not need the `xlmns` (and you can add it if you want it). I have forked the plunker ([link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZHfcztiiCfK8LcWC5Z1j?p=preview)) with the new code. Now the svg file does not have the `xmlns` attribute. Notice the `makeInline` function that accepts the `object` id, then creates in inline `svg` inside a `div` with a modified `id`. Afterwards, you can use that new `id` (or a class that you add) to identify the newly created element. The function also removes the original object to avoid cluttering.

Comment: When I press the button, the color isn't changed at all in none of the groups of svg if I use either of 2 ways you provided. Your code from codepen link works as I want, but you work directly on SVG code. Calling the svg in <object> tag, that code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Changing SVG external file's code is not a solution for me. I'm not allowed to do this. 
I have tried to use $(window).load() and then to call the object like this: var svg = document.getElementById("p1").contentDocument.documentElement; but with no success. 
The problem with jQuery I think doesn't apply to me because I can access the document content of an <object> with an svg provided in the data attribute.
It seemed for me logic the solution you gave me before editing the answer. I can't figure it out why is not working for external SVGs.

Comment: With this limitation, I would go for something different. Please, see updated answer.

Comment: With the svg's code from my question and with the example you provided in edit 2, I manged to change color of one object. I did identify each linearGradient by id like this: ($(svg).contents().find("#SVGID_2_ stop, #SVGID_3_ stop, #SVGID_4_").each(function ()). It's not the most simple and elegant solution (if I'd have a svg with many linearGradient elements, this solution is hard to implement). This is why I insist to use group <g> which should incorporate the linearGradients I want to change. But I see is not that simple how I thought it should be.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be better to write every `linearGradient` you need and then set and change the `fill` property of each object. This way you don't need to cycle through `stop`s and you have more flexibility.